# Workflow for stock prediction in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, python, time-series, data-science-model, finance

I'm trying to find the best workflow for a stock prediction problem.

My idea goes as follows : I will use a classfication and a regression at the same time

- Classification (-1 ; 0 ; 1)
- Regression (float) => I will classify the output in the end just like the classification to make a decision (if the float number is really close to 0, it will be a zero for me)

The pipeline of the classification and regression will be the same:

1. Data engineer with X (increase X with moving averages, Z score, lags etc of the current X)
2. Remove outliers from X
3. Scale X
4. Split (train, validate, predict) => ex(if length of all data is 120 : train = 118, validate = 1 , predict = 1)
5. Calculate important features to reduce dataset => ***Question 1 : Feature importance should be done on train or validate ? I think train***
6. Remove colinearity from the selected features (using VIF)
7. Tunning parameters => ***Question 2 : Apply on train or validate ? Train in my opinion***
8. ***Question 3 : Where I can use the validation in this case if the length is 1 ?***

I think I'm missing something. Of course I will run a backtest on this framework, but I want be sure that in term of biais I'm not violating something or something else.

If you got any ressources or something else, please share

Comment: The overall approach seems correct, but you can apply more simple models for a start. I tell that because stock markets are particularly difficult to predict due to the high noise they have and the complexity between feature. For example, some features could be meaningful during a specific period of time, whereas other could be meaningful in a different one. But generally speaking, there are often most significant feature at any time. So noise reduction, more simple model at start and select the most significant features could have good predicitons.

Comment: Thanks @NicolasMartin for your response. In my experience, the best results were yielded by RandomF and LinearR, more complicated ones always underperformed. However my project is a little bit more general. I want to create a framework and let the user use the model that he wants. So what I'm trying to do is create this framework with all the avalaible options. I just want to get right the timeline for every step until predicting that number. I don't know if I'm clear enough

Comment: Actually, you want to create a time series playground? Something like this service? https://daitan-innovation.github.io/timeseries-playground/

Comment: Hey, this looks great, thank you @NicolasMartin. I have a regression problem not a time series one but it will be quite useful for futue developpements

Comment: You're welcome @GeriLeka. My mistake: I thought you wanted to make predictions including also timeseries models, and then a classification. Using relative values (= fluctuations) instead of absolute values could be better but it depends on the model. Are you considering the time line range also?

Comment: What do you mean by timeline range? 
The idea would be to use singnal from a regression and a classifcation en price returns. As you mention, I might add a time series model too so I can split the decision in 3.

Comment: According to my past experience, it is difficult to classify in long time ranges, like 120 days in a row, using raw values. Maybe I'm wrong, but it made more sense to classify several indices in short ranges (ex: 5 to 20 days) using relatives values (ex: increase of 3, then drop of -2, etc.) to classify data dynamics properly. In this way, you can detect easily correlations between indices and find interesting facts. A correlation analysis might be useful to detect which indices are most relevant.

Comment: Do you have any paper on this methodology to suggest? Currently I have been trying to predict t+1. I do a time series cross validation with hyperparameters to find the best model using distance probability to truthness (ex: If the outcome should have been 1 and all the models predict 1, I take the one that has the highest predict_proba in that class). However the backtest is under constrcution so not sure if this is the right way, even if it is, the model is as good as the data you inject in. Statistically my walkthrough I think is correct (Hope so) !

Comment: It is difficult to say without a concrete example (even a false one). Could you modify the original question adding an example?

Comment: I don't think changing the question will be beneficial as I am trying to find the standart walkthrough for stock predicting using machine learning. If someone has a different walkthrough better than mine that is used by the financial sector should post it.

Comment: The walktrough depends on the algorithms and tools you are using. The one you have defined seems correct, but contains several questions. I recommend to post specific questions separatelly to know if the steps are correctly done. Feature importance and tuning parameters should be done with the biggest volume of data indeed (=train data).